# トップページなどが大幅に英語へ戻っている

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

[image: SOjaのトップページのスクリーンショットです。通常のレイアウトなのですが、多くの箇所が英語に戻っています。]

トップページでいくつかの要素が英語になっています。ここだけでなく、メニューやヘルプなど複数個所が英語になっています。

現状 https://ja.traducir.win に新しい string ができているわけでもありませんでした。システム側のバグではないでしょうか？

---

It seems that our translation is not reflected to several pages in our site. Is it a bug of the system?

Comment: 再現出来ない環境がある場合の参考として、念のため、ウェブアーカイブを取得しておきました ([メイン](https://web.archive.org/web/20190905144148/https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)、[メタ](https://web.archive.org/web/20190905144711/https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/))。

Comment: 関連: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2019年9月6日0時 (JST) 現在、大方の翻訳が反映されたようです (まだ反映されていない部分もあります)。原因がよく分かりませんが、他のすべての international sites でも同様の現象が起こっていたので ([例](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4315))、何かしらバグだったのだろうと思います。

Comment: 現状では、「サイト統計情報」ボックスの日本語が英語のままになっているようなので、まだ翻訳の反映されていない部分が存在すると思われます。

Comment: む、本当ですね。回答を更新しました。

Comment: サイト統計情報も元に戻りました。